# Why do ZeroMQ libraries provide different throughput rates depending on the build?

Tags: c++, message-queue, zeromq

ZeroMQ's git repo provides some performance benchmark tools. Exes for benchmarking are included when the repo is built and the benchmarks show great performance. Now, if I take the same source files and built them from my own Makefile, I notice a 7-8x performance slowdown in comparison.

This is also consistent with some benchmarks that I developed independently. The benchmarks I developed show underwhelming performance from zmq when I know it should be providing much higher throughput. This makes me suspect there may be some parameter tuning which should be done during the build process.

If there is some tuning to be done to address this wide inconsistency in the provided benchmarks versus my independent benchmarks, there doesn't seem to be anything in zmq's documentation to address this.

Comment: Different compiler options? Optimization on or off?

Comment: Must be something like that... been trying to look at options used by zmq's build. It's a very complicated build, though. Also, the exe uses an autogenerated script as well. Many lines of code to look at!